# excel vba - error 1004,method rangeof object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

i have a custom made calendar on a worksheet and this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Count > 6 Then Exit Sub
With Sheet10
 If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("D6:J10,D12:J16,D18:J22,D24:J28,D30:J34,D36:J40")) Is Nothing Then (*****)
 If Target.Offset(-1, 0).value <> Empty Then .Range("M3").value = Target.Offset(-1, 0).value
 .Range("B7").value = Target.Address
 End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I keep getting error 1004 for line (*****).What's even more weird is that i don't get it all the time!

Comment: is this code in the code for sheet10?

Comment: yes of course!!

Comment: Then use `With Me` instead

Comment: doesnt work either...

Comment: then it is the data, because it works for me without issue.

Comment: but what could be wrong with the data and what differencedoes it make what the range contains?(all those cells are blank by the way atm)